# Python Strings How do you find the "spaces" in a string?

Tags: python, string

What is the proper way to verify there is no space in a string and then print an error message?

I do not know the corerct if, then statement for verify space in a string.

Comment: have a look to `str.isspace`: it detects white spaces, `\t`, `\n`,...

Comment: To detect at least one space (ASCII 32), use `if ' ' in mystring:`

Comment: To detect at least one whitespace, use `import re` followed by `if re.search(r'\s'):`

Comment: To detect all whitespace, non-empty: use `if mystring.isspace():`

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask), which has tips like starting with your own research.